# Set Window-Focus/Bring it to Foreground

Tags: java, window, focus

I need to set a focus on a window / bring the application to foreground.
I tried it with `.toFront()` but it only works if it's called from the actual application that has the actual focus on it.

How can I let my java application get back it's focus itself, once it loses it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
stage.requestFocus()
```

where `stage` is your stage, this should make your stage the focused window.